# How to get last modified date and time in Filesystem?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, filesystems

Hi I am trying to get last modified date and time of file, which is stored in my local device memory directory. Is is possible to get lastmodifieddate in filesystem?

Till now i have been trying with the below code

```
 function checkLastModifiedDate(){
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.
    externalRootDirectory 
    +"Download/SMU/File Repo/SMUDE_Connect_User_Guide.pdf",  
        function(fs) {
            LastModifiedDateOfFile(fs);
    }, failFiles);  

function failFiles(error) {
    if (error.code == FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR)
        toastr.error('User guide manual not exists.', 'Information')
    else if (error.code == FileError.SECURITY_ERR)
        console.log("Message : SECURITY_ERR")
    else if (error.code == FileError.ABORT_ERR)
        console.log("Message : ABORT_ERR")
    else if (error.code == FileError.NOT_READABLE_ERR)
        console.log("Message : NOT_READABLE_ERR")
    else if (error.code == FileError.ENCODING_ERR)
        console.log("Message : ENCODING_ERR")
    else if (error.code == FileError.NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR)
        console.log("Message : NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR")
    else if (error.code == FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR)
        console.log("Message : INVALID_STATE_ERR")
    else if (error.code == FileError.SYNTAX_ERR)
        console.log("Message : SYNTAX_ERR")
    else if (error.code == FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR)
        console.log("Message :  INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR")
    else if (error.code == FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
        console.log("Message : QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR")
    else if (error.code == FileError.PATH_EXISTS_ERR)
        console.log("Message : PATH_EXISTS_ERR")
}
}

function LastModifiedDateOfFile(fileEntry){
var lastMod = fileEntry.lastModifiedDate;
//alert("lastMod - "+lastMod);
//var date = new Date(fileEntry.lastModified);
//alert("date - "+date);
}
```

referred links http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

and this way we can do but im not choosing files through input tag
http://jsbin.com/ajepef/1/edit?html,output

Everytime is showing 'undefined', I am not sure lastmodifeddate attribute is there or not.
If anybody know please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "YOUR_FILE_NAME", gotFile, fail);

function fail(e) {
    console.log("FileSystem Error");
    console.dir(e);
}

function gotFile(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        console.log(file.lastModifiedDate);        
    });
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It is working in android. But for ios it is returning current time instead of returning file's actual modification time. Is there any other work around to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `file()` method of `fileEntry`.Change your `LastModifiedDateOfFile` function as followings:

```
function LastModifiedDateOfFile(fileEntry){
    fileEntry.file(successFile,errorFile);

    function successFile(entry){
        alert(entry.lastModified);
    }

    function errorFile(error){
        alert("error");
    }
}
```